# Cytoscape won't let me upload table to a network collection the only option was to unassigned table. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Tags: cytoscape

the drop-down option isn't available so my table is automatically imported as unassigned table. Anybody come across this issue before? Or is there something wrong with my table setting?

[cytoscape screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBuCQ.png)

Comment: Would you like to show the image in your question itself, using upload image option?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you were expecting.  According to the screenshot, you don't have any networks open, so an imported table can only be unassigned.  If, on the other hand, you are trying to import a network, you need to use import network from file, not import table from file.

-- scooter

Comment: I see. I thought the first step to building a network is to import a table first. Do I have to create a new empty network first before the table can be assigned to the network?

Comment: No, if you create an empty network, you'll just wind up with an empty table since there won't be any nodes to map to.  What you need to do is to use Import Network from File, and then provide it you data file.  That will give you a network that you can work with.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and ended up spending 3-4 hours on this.

[image]

This icon on the tool-bar allows loading of networks from tables without any issue. I was very lucky to find this solution in a video on YouTube(!): https://youtu.be/Z8jUmJL2HFw?t=52, but not in the Cytoscapes documentation.

To me, Cytoscape's file import system felt very un-intuitive. I am not sure why cytoscape does not have a unified import system for loading simple (csv/tsv) tables. Following are few ways that did not work in my case. I am using version 3.9.0. In both of these cases the table got imported as 'Unassigned table'.

1. Drag and drop 'Edge Table'/'Network table'.
2. File > Import > Import from file

I went through the documentation and I am still not sure what is the use of 'Unassigned table'. How to assign the columns as source, target etc in the 'Unassigned table'? Even the sample tables shown in the Cytoscape's manual did the same(!).

By the way, I am not sure why the Cytoscape's documentation is not intuitive. For example, I googled 'cytoscape import table' and this slide show showed up as a 1st result: https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape-tutorials/protocols/importing-data-from-tables/#/5 . From the title of the slideshow i.e. 'Importing data from tables', I assumed that it will guide me through how to generate network from tabular data. However, instead it shows how to load data for nodes, which does not create a network(!). Why not demonstrate how to load edge/network data and guide us through the process till the generation of the network? I hope this will improve in next versions of CytoScape.

Anyways, I hope the solution helps.